# Check if row record exists with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I want to check if row record by id exists. I tried this:

```
public Optional<PaymentTransactions> transactionByUnique_Id( String unique_id ) throws Exception
{
    String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.unique_id = :unique_id";
    TypedQuery<PaymentTransactions> query = entityManager.createQuery( hql, PaymentTransactions.class ) .setParameter( "unique_id", unique_id );
    Optional<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransaction = query.getResultList().stream().findFirst();
    return paymentTransaction;
}

Optional<PaymentTransactions> tnx = transactionsService.transactionByUnique_Id( transaction.getTransactionId() );

if(tnx.isPresent())
{
    return "test";
    // This method should be called only when DB record exists
}
```

But I alway get present object. What is the proper way to implement this check.

Comment: `return new "test";`? That is not valid Java. If you actually run that code, and if the transaction is always present, it simply means that you're always calling it with an ID that, indeed, exists. Note that if unique_id is the ID of your entity, you just need to call EntityManager.find(). That's what it's for.

Comment: Sorry, typo mistake. Can you give some advice how to fix the present code?

Comment: There is nothing to fix. It's correct. (It still doesn't respect the Java naming conventions, though).